# Python - location of a word in a file wrt beginning of the file

Tags: python, file, search, indexing, position

I want to get a position of a word in a file from the beginning of the file. It should count \n, \r, \t also while counting the position. I tried index and find commands but they work on individual line and does not give location from the beginning. Can someone suggest anything? I have written below code:

```
def findword(filename:str, word:str):
    try:
        file = open(filename, 'r')
        count = 0
        occurances = []
        for line in file:
            if word in line:
                print("word found")
                occurance = line.find(word)
                occurances.append(occurance)
                print(occurance)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
        occurances.sort()
        print(occurances)
        if count == 0:
            print("word not found")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("warning: file not found")
        return -1
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about something like: `open(filename, 'r').read().index('text to find')`. Using `read()` will read the whole file into one string.

Comment: You can read the whole file: `file.read()` and then find the index: `file.read().index(word)`. Is that not good enough?